# Disabling Cellular Network communication on Android Device

Tags: android, geolocation

I am writing a research paper for my mobile computing class, which will compare empirically the horizontal and vertical location accuracy of the GPS receiver, Wi-Fi triangulation, and cell tower triangulation on a Droid BIONIC against known survey-grade GPS measurements. To achieve this I need to test each approach in isolation from each other as opposed to them working in conjunction to determine location. Is there a way to disable network connections programmatically? I have looked at the [Criteria class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html) in the android.location package, but those are as the name implies: "criteria". I haven't found anything in the API documentation that would allow me to specifically designate which provider to use when determining geolocation, nor any algorithms on a Google search.

EDIT: Is it as simple as providing a true or false value for the following methods in the [LocationProvider class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html)?

```
requiresCell()
requiresNetwork()
requiresSatellite()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technically isn't selecting the provider programmatically but on my DROID X I can do the following steps to disable data traveling over the network:

Settings > Battery and Data Manager > Data Delivery > Data Enabled / Background Data

I should be able to use this technique in conjunction with the LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER (and hopefully the DROID Bionic) to isolate the cellular network and the WiFi. I'll let y'all know how it works out.

**UPDATE**

For those of you who are interested, I have been conducting many hours of research into this even after my paper was completed. This has not been tested, but from what I gleaned from the documentation one can programatically toggle between network providers by the use of  the [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) class in the [android.net](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/package-summary.html) package. Additionally, the WiFi can be manipulated in many more ways via the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) class in the [android.net.wifi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/package-summary.html) package.

I have not had a chance to incorporate either of these approaches into an application that also uses the android.location package. However, I don't think it would be a stretch to incorporate some functionality where you use the methods of the two aforementioned classes to toggle which provider you want. Then when this method is called:

```
requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
```

where the provider is the [NETWORK_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER) variable, the variable would automatically assume the provider that was toggled beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Well the closest you can get I think is `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` or `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` or both. You can feed these flags into the `LocationManager`'s `requestLocationUpdates()` as a filter.

Try implementing the `LocationListener`'s `onProviderEnabled()`/`onProviderDisabled()` to see if you can filter even further between WiFi and Cell Tower.

**Edit:** You could take out the SIM card and use only the WiFi to determine location and vice-versa (disable WiFi) to force the use of the towers.

Comment: It appears that the LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER "determines location based on availability of cell tower and WiFi access points." It also says that it requires "either of the permissions android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION." Does this imply that one of the permission types, i.e. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, corresponds to either the cellular network or a Wi-Fi network? The only way I see to differentiate them is using criteria. But a cellular network or a wi-fi network could both meet a certain criteria, so this is not a error-free approach.

Comment: ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION implies ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION so for the network if you have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION you don't need the other one. Also ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is mainly for GPS location. There is no definitive way to separate WiFi from the towers. Cell tower triangulation would require cooperation from the operator.

Comment: I didn't see your edit before I posted, but that sounds like a more full proof technique. Thanks.

Comment: I want to accept both of them if possible. Both represent legitimate solution.